# More Efficient Version of this Correlated Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I've got 3 different tables and I need to pull data once from 2 of them, and twice from the third. The tables are `jobs`, `customers`, and `customers_attributes`. I'm trying to pull data for a specific job, and part of that data is information about the customer who owns the job. Customer data is stored in `customers_attributes` where the type of data is defined as an integer that corresponds with a type(using strings here for simplicity's sake) and then a content field contains the data itself.

In this case, I need to pull 2 rows from the `customers_attributes` table that correspond to the customer that corresponds to the job. One row for 'PhoneNumber', and another row for 'CustomerInfo'. I used an INNER JOIN for one of them, but because I can't put WHERE values for both, I used a subquery for the other one. I think this is really nasty and I'm sure there's got to be a cleaner way of doing it:

```
SELECT jobs.*, customers.Name AS CustomerName,
       customers_attributes.Content AS PhoneNumber,
       (     SELECT `Content`
             FROM customers_attributes
             WHERE Type = 'CustomerInfo' AND ForeignCustomer = jobs.Customer
             LIMIT 1) AS CustomerInfo
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN customers ON jobs.Customer = customers.ID
INNER JOIN customers_attributes ON jobs.Customer = customers_attributes.ForeignCustomer
WHERE jobs.ID = $jobID AND customers_attributes.Type = 'PhoneNumber'
LIMIT 1
```

I should mention that a customer could have multiple rows for the same attribute if they have more than 1 job, and this query ideally should either return the latest information, or the information that was submitted at the same time as the job(based on corresponding ID orders).

Comment: Remember to always `'` quote your `$vars`, or mysql_real_escape_string will not work!

Comment: The variable in question here was typecasted to an integer, should I still be quoting it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the same table again under a different alias.

```
SELECT j.*, c.Name AS CustomerName,
       ca.Content AS PhoneNumber,
       ca2.Content as CustomerInfo
FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN customers c ON j.Customer = c.ID
INNER JOIN customers_attributes ca ON (j.Customer = ca.ForeignCustomer)
INNER JOIN customers_attributes ca2 ON (j.Customer = ca2.ForeignCustomer)
WHERE j.ID = '$jobID' 
  AND ca.Type = 'PhoneNumber'
  AND ca2.Type = 'CustomerInfo'
LIMIT 1
```

**Warning**
It looks like you're using PHP. If you *must* insist on using the outdated `mysql_` library and not the much improved `mysqli_` lib.
Please remember to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` and to quote your `$vars`.
If not you'll be hid by SQL-injection problems.

Comment: Already using mysqli, and escaping the queries. In this case I typecasted the $jobID variable to an int. I would use PDO, but my host didn't have the plugin(I know, ridiculous). Also, that looks perfect, wish I'd known that little trick a while ago..

Comment: Also, should I be quoting integer variables? I was under the impression that I should only be doing that with strings

Comment: In MySQL (and MySQL only), you can quote ints without any problem.